# BlackBerry 6: creating white rectangle image with text and gradient

Tags: image, blackberry, bitmap, paint

I'm trying to create a custom component looking like a rectangle radio dial:

[image]

As a base I'm taking the custom [ScrollableImageField.java](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-scrollable-image-field/ta-p/444955) component and passing it an image from project resources in my Screen:

```
_dial = new FMRadioDial(EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("big_dial.png"));
_dial = new FMRadioDial(bmp);
add(_dial);
```

This works well and I can scroll an image by the optical touch pad and also by swiping the Torch screen.

Then I'm trying to generate a white rectangle image myself:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Display.getWidth()*4, Display.getHeight()/2);
_dial = new FMRadioDial(bmp);
add(_dial);
```

this compiles, but I get a black image.

So my question is: how to generate an image (should I use Bitmap or maybe EncodedImage here?) from the code and how can I paint a white rectangle, a gradient and some text into it?

Thank you!
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can do something like this:

```
int bmpWidth = 100;
    int bmpHeight = 100;        
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bmpWidth,bmpHeight);
    Graphics g = new Graphics(bmp);
    int[] X_PTS = { 0, 0, bmpWidth, bmpWidth };
    int[] Y_PTS = { 0, bmpHeight, bmpHeight, 0 };
    int[] drawColors = {0x646464, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0x646464 };           
    g.drawShadedFilledPath(X_PTS, Y_PTS, null, drawColors, null);        
    g.setColor(0x0000ff);
    g.drawText("TEXT", 50, 50);
```

But if you want to just display it, you don't need to create Bitmap,
 you can extend Field and  override  paint method:

```
public class CustomField extends Field {    

private int myWidth = 200;
private int myHeight = 100;

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return myWidth;
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return myHeight;
}

protected void layout(int width, int height) {              
    setExtent(myWidth, myHeight);
}

protected void paint(Graphics g) {
    int[] X_PTS = { 0, 0, myWidth, myWidth };
    int[] Y_PTS = { 0, myHeight, myHeight, 0 };
    int[] drawColors = {0x646464, 0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0x646464 };           
    g.drawShadedFilledPath(X_PTS, Y_PTS, null, drawColors, null);        
    g.setColor(0x0000ff);
    g.drawText("TEXT", 50, 50); }
```

}

Comment: True, I don't need a Bitmap, I will paint stuff in paint()